# goroutines done channel unbuffered channel

Tags: channel, goroutine

In unbuffered channel by default sends and receives block until both the sender and receiver are ready.

```
package main
    
    import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
    )
    
    func worker(done chan bool) {
        fmt.Print("working...")
        fmt.Println("done")
    
        done <- true
    }
    
    func main() {
    
        done := make(chan bool)
        go worker(done)
    
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        <-done
    }
```

But the above code is executed instantly. It should wait for 5 seconds right ?

Comment: Where are you testing the above code? Locally I can see waiting for 5 seconds.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/OoJTka3ycTO
Go playground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the above on playground then I guess you are hitting the same case as this question [Why does time.Sleep not work if there are no further statements to execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58079847/why-does-time-sleep-not-work-if-there-are-no-further-statements-to-execute)